# How can I plot a ROC curve with AUC?

Tags: r, roc, auc

I am trying to classify two different cases. Therefore I  built decision trees,  the confusion matrix and calculated the accuracy, sensitivity and the specificitvy. I ran my program 100 times, so I have 100 accuracy, sensitivity and specificitvy values.

**What I want to do** now is to plot the ROC curve with the AUC. I did some researches and all these examples were discussing probabilities and I don't know what exactly these are.

So can anyone help me to plot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a package like pROC, which may be easier than creating it yourself. You use the roc() function to create a roc object and then plot() to plot the object and create the ROC curve.

Also, it doesn't sound like you are going about this in the right way. The ROC curve is calculated from sensitivity and specificity values taken at different cut points across the range of possible probabilities from you model i.e. at cut points between 0 and 1. You don't need to create 100 sets of model predictions, just one model will suffice.

Try something like this, where y is your response variable and p is the vector of probability values output by your model:

```
plot(roc(y, p)), print.auc = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Cleland for your comment! From where do I get my possible probabilities? Like how are these calculated?

Comment: Have a look at the predict() function for the type of model you have built. Usually there will be options to output a probability score for each observation.

Comment: Okay, I will have a deeper look at my predict function. Thanks!